# Couldn't Daryl have "claimed" Rick, Carl and Michonne as per the rules of his group?

Tags: the-walking-dead

It seems like an easy way around the predicament, and with less violence. The group leader seemed to be a stickler for the rules he created.

Answer (score 7):

Rick had killed Lou, a member of the Claimers, so either revenge for that death overrides any "claim" by Daryl, or you could say that a claim had already been made on Rick prior to Daryl joining up with the Claimers.

Comment: One could also argue that their rules regarding lying and cheating superseded the rules of "claiming" as he had the squirrel-thief killed for lying about planting the kill on Daryl. To Joe, killing one of their members would trump any claim Daryl tried to make over Rick.

Answer (score 0):

These were not good men. First, Rick would have had to be killed for hurting the group and then Michonne and Carl would likely have been raped and murdered (as neither of them would likely stop fighting). He might have been able to "claim" them first, but he was already on the outs with the group and they would have found a way to kill him or cause him to seem to have broken the group's "rules".